# Creating new Redmine user via console gives valid? => false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

Saving fails due to user not being valid. Here is what I'm running in the console:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails c

clear_password = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(12)
salt = User.generate_salt
hashed_password = User.hash_password("#{salt}#{User.hash_password clear_password}")

admin_user = User.new({firstname: 'Bob', lastname: 'Doe', mail: 'john@doe.com'})
admin_user.login = 'adminuser'
admin_user.admin = true
admin_user.mail_notification = true
admin_user.status = 1
admin_user.salt = salt
admin_user.hashed_password = hashed_password

admin_user.valid?
User Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`type` IN ('User', 'AnonymousUser') AND `users`.`login` = 'adminuser' LIMIT 1
User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`type` IN ('User', 'AnonymousUser') AND `users`.`mail` = 'bob@doe.com' LIMIT 1
 => false
```

This hardly gives me a debug message since there currently are no users in the db. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

---

**Update**

I went down the line calling `valid?` after setting each property. The problem appears to be with `mail_notification`. I removed it and seems to produce valid. Will update with answer when I have fully resolved.

Comment: What's the validation error?

Comment: It just says `User Exists` and the query that is probably causing the error. However, there are 0 users so it cannot exist. It is validated by the default Redmine `User` model.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
user.save!
```

To force the code to raise an exception with a message about why it is failing or use:

```
user.save
puts user.errors.full_messages.join(", ")
```

To print all the error messages for the object creation so you can figure out what's missing.